# Sms text not sending

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

I'm having issues getting an sms text to send. When I click the button, nothing happens. No message or anything.
What doesn't make sense is that it works as a standalone app for sms sending, but if I integrate the code into my larger project, it doesn't send the sms. Nothing happens.
Something has to conflicting with Smsmanager or something. Can anyone give me advice on why it doesn't work anymore?

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="android_auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".engine.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ui.MapsActivity1">

        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application" android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCMFYfJ6aOuxJk3W0vmhF6Nou3TP_qIU6c" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!--
     Main music service, provides media browsing and media playback services to
             consumers through MediaBrowserService and MediaSession. Consumers connect to it through
             MediaBrowser (for browsing) and MediaController (for playback control)
            -->
        <service android:name=".MyMusicService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".MyMessagingService" />

        <receiver android:name=".MessageReadReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.zachboone.myapplication.ACTION_MESSAGE_READ" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".MessageReplyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.zachboone.myapplication.ACTION_MESSAGE_REPLY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>




</manifest>
```

SendSmsActivity.java

```
package android_auto.engine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android_auto.R;


public class SendSmsActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textPhoneNo;
    EditText textSMS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SendSmsActivity.this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);


                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, pendingIntent, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_sms.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Phone Number : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:phoneNumber="true" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSMS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter SMS Message : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSMS"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the logcat (please don't filter the logcat, otherwise you wmight miss somethng important)? How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your code in click listener to this

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SendSmsActivity.this, 0,new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, pendingIntent, null);
```

Hope this helps you making it working.

Comment: Change `this` to `SendSmsActivity.this`

Comment: I made the change and it compiled, but when I run it on my phone, the send button still does nothing. I updated SendSmsActivity.java above with new changes

Comment: Did you got any exception during this. First check, which condition is getting meet in order to debug this. You need some debugging in order to find the problem whether your listener is getting called or not.

Comment: I do see one error in the log that i'm not sure is related. GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

Comment: That is not seems to be related to this one.
First try to make sure if your `onclick` section is being executed or not. Put some alert there to verify whether your listener is working or not.

Comment: The sms standalone I built that worked didn't work in the emulator. I had to run it on my phone. How can I debug it if the button doesn't respond in the emulator, but does on phone

Comment: When emulator is very slow, your listener unable to respond on time due to which button not seems to be working. Try using Genymotion for this purpose. It is a good emulator and might resolve your problem if you want to check it on emulator.

Comment: Do you have any ideas that don't cost money?

Comment: You can try a good emulator because that won't cost you money and you can check your output on it. And one more thing, try to give more `RAM` to your emulator. Moreover, you can search for "How to run your emulator fast"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104456/discussion-between-xkorpion-and-user6680).

Comment: Here's something new I found. In the standalone version in the emulator when I hit the button Send it says Sms Failed, but the toast never appears when I click the button in the version integrated into my project.